# Touches Ended not being called

Tags: ios, multi-touch

I've playing around with recognizing the touches in an iOS Application, and I have this simple code

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[touches count]);
 [touches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
     UITouch *touch = obj;
     CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
     NSLog(@"B x:%f - y:%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
 }];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 [touches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    UITouch *touch = obj;
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
    NSLog(@"E x:%f - y:%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
 }];
}
```

The touchesBegan is being called fine, if I place from 1 finger up to 5 fingers on the screen at the same time, I see it being called with the correct information

The same doesn't happen with `touchesBegan`, many time if I have 3 fingers on the screen and remove them simultaneously, I only see information on 2 touches being ended (and sometimes even 1). If I take the fingers out one at a time, the method also usually gets called 2 times (sometimes 1, although rarely it will be called the correct 3 times)
As the number of touches increases, also the likely hood of some information not being shown in the `touchesEnded` method

Methods `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` are also implemented, with the same logic

Can someone explain this behavior? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Was there an accepted answer?

Answer (score 38):

You'd have to set `recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false` in Swift or `recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;` in Objective-C

Answer (score 25):

Try removing any Gesture Recognizers you have on that view. They can interfere with `touchesEnded`.

Comment: All events ? Would swipes and touch events interfere with each other ?

Comment: I also experience the same thing, if multiple gesture recognizers interfere ```-touchesEnded:``` or ```-touchesCanelled:``` can be omitted for one of them.
**Important:** don't rely on those methods to reset/cleanup your gesture recognizer state. Instead override ```-reset``` method for you cleanup logic which is called even though ```-touchesEnded:``` are ```-touchesCanelled:``` not.

Comment: You saved me! Thank you. Works perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You have to override all touch methods if you do not call super's implementation. So you have to also implement the `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`
 methods. Implementations can be empty but you have to do it.

> **`touchesBegan:withEvent:`**
>
> If you override this method without calling super (a common use
>   pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch
>   events, if only as stub (empty) implementations.

Based on [UIResponder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a)

Comment: I didn't add this information for brevity, but I do have all 4 methods implemented

Comment: I have all 4 implemented but i touchesEnded is still not being called

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding the `UIView`'s `hitTest` method:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   return self;
}
```

It is possible that when you lift fingers they are not recognised as being in the `UIView`, so`touchesEnded` is not called.

Comment: I have seen this quite a few times with people stuck with similar issues

Answer (score 2):

- Tap gestures (simple, long, 2xshort, 2xfingers tap) do not allow the calls Touches Ended / Canceled if cancelsTouchesInView == NO
- They allow its calling ONLY IF cancelsTouchesInView property is the default YES
- Pinch gesture allows all the calls (to Touches Begin / Moved / Ended / Canceled) ONLY IF cancelsTouchesInView property is set to NO
- If for the pinch gesture the cancelsTouchesInView property would have been YES, touchesMoved would not have been called

Inside info:

> I am using:
>
> - 1 finger UITapGestureRecognizer
> - 1 finger UILongPressGestureRecognizer
> - 1 finger double tap UITapGestureRecognizer
> - 2 fingers tap UITapGestureRecognizer
> - 1 UIPinchGestureRecognizer
>
> And also should receive one finger panning. But what i have found out is that the
>   Pinch gesture was not Ending even if the user had risen one finger.
>   Somehow iOS is still calling the Pinch's selector with "Changed"
>   state.
>
> My solution was to use the touchesBegin/Moved/Ended to catch the pan
>   and use the number of active touches as safety check in case the pinch
>   selector would be called.

Other settings i had to use in making the above configuration:

```
self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
[oneFingerTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:oneFingerLongPressRecognizer];
[oneFingerTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:oneFingerDoubleTapRecognizer];
[oneFingerLongPressRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:oneFingerDoubleTapRecognizer];
[twoFingersTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:twoFingersPinch];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with this simple code in the touches ended:

```
NSInteger touchCount = 0;
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
   touchCount++;
    if([[event allTouches]count] == touchCount){
       // do what you have to do here
    }
}
```

//  You will get a warning here but don't care about it

I hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even after defining all four touch handlers. I also didn't have any active recognizers.

The solution for me was to simply enable multi touch events on my view, like so

```
self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

which magically solved the problem.

Note that I did get "multi touch" events even before this, i.e. events for multiple fingers at the same time, but I had the above issue that not all of them were ended properly.

Hope that helps someone! :)