# UIControl subclass is receiving "touchesCancelled" instead of "touchesEnded"

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol

In my project, I have the main view, in which I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, and inside this main view, I have a subview that is a custom `UIControl`, which I will call `UICustomButton`.

The `UICustomButton` overrides the following methods of `UIControl`:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        pressAnimation()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        releaseAnimation()
        listener?.onClick(sender: self)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        releaseAnimation()
    }
```

The problem I am having is, all "click touches" are hitting the following callbacks:

- `touchesBegan`
- `touchesCancelled`

The `touchesEnded` callback is not being called, it's kinda being ignored and I don't know why.

How can I make `touchesEnded` be called instead of `touchesCancelled` on a touch action?

---

Some facts:

- if I remove the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the parent view, everything works fine;
- even not calling the `supers` and overriding all `touches` methods, the `touchesCancelled` is called =/;
- if I do a "long touch" or do a "big moving gesture", `touchesEnded` is called :o.

Comment: I think this answer might be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038660/4981847

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour for a view that has a gesture recogniser attached.

The `UIGestureRecognizer` documentation says "If a gesture recognizer recognizes its gesture, the remaining touches for the view are cancelled":

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer

The property `cancelsTouchesInView` (which defaults to `true`), determines whether or not touches are cancelled when a gesture is recognized:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624218-cancelstouchesinview

Because a long touch and a swipe are *not* recognized by a tap recognizer, it doesn't interfere with them. It *only* intervenes when it recognizes a tap.

If you set the recognizer's `cancelsTouchesInView` property to `false`, then the touches shouldn't be cancelled, and the `touchesEnded(_:with:)` method will be called as usual.

You can set that property either in code or in Interface Builder (if you added your gesture recognizer by dragging it out in your storyboard).

Comment: Hello, @PetMorris. Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It worked, `touchesEnded()` is now being called \o/. But the problem I am having now is that both callbacks, `touchesEnded()` and the one from the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the parent view are being fired. Is there any way I can make only the `UICustomButton`\`s callback to be called? Thanks o/

Comment: You’ll have to assign a delegate to your recognizer. Check out UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. Its gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:) method returns a Bool which states whether or not the touch should be handled by the recognizer. You’ll need to judge the location of the touch and if it’s within the bounds of your custom control return false from this delegate method.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, @PeteMorris. That's what I've done. But I was wondering if there were another ways to do that. I'll stick to that solution then. Cheers \ o /